geom_sf creates additional whitespace
I am trying to make a plot of an sf object and safe it to a pdf (there are several other plots in this pdf and I want them all in one document to make my data visible "at a glance").
library(tidyverse)
library(terra)
library(rnaturalearth)

### get a shapefile
world <- ne_countries(scale="medium", return="sf")

### plot
pdf("reprex.pdf", paper="a4r")
world
dev.off()


The problem is, that the map is not automatically fit to the entire page, but centered leaving a whole lot of whitespace around it. I can't for the life of me figure out how to fit the plot to the entire page. 
At first I thought that ggplot was creating all kinds of whitespace around the plot (i.e., "leaving space" for legends etc.) as that was an issue previously, but as you can see only a little bit of whitespace is created aroudn the plot, which would be entirely tolerable for my needs 

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
    
    # before saving on pdf create the plot without margins using ggplot
        plot_world <- ggplot(data = world) +
          geom_sf() +
          theme_void() +  # removing axes and background !
          theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))  # removing margins 
    
    # then save the pdf
        pdf("reprex.pdf", width = 11.69, height = 8.27)  # size A4 (landscape orientation)
       print(plot_world)
       dev.off()


The margin only improved things slightly (as the plot margins are already small, see second image above). But the fact that you gave the dimensions of a4 (rotated) instead of the paper="a4r" seems to have done the trick. Why this is the case is entirely beyond me however ;-).

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
